# get values from getter and setter methods in java for inserting into Mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, getter-setter

How to get values from getter and setter methods in java to insert into Mongodb.I used the below code to insert in to mongodb

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycol");
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("id","Hello" ).
                         append("description", "database").
                            append("likes", 100).
                            append("url", "http://http://www.flowersofindia.net/").
                            append("by", "Rose");
                         coll.insert(doc);
```

The above given are some Hard code values.But i need to take the values from setter method thet i have wrote.This is my getter and setter class.

```
public class Encapsulation {
    private String id;
    private String product_name;
    private String product_url;
    private String product_image;
    private String product_price;
    private String product_src;
    private String country;
    private String date;
    private String Category;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }
    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }
    public String getProduct_url() {
        return product_url;
    }
    public void setProduct_url(String product_url) {
        this.product_url = product_url;
    }
    public String getProduct_image() {
        return product_image;
    }
    public void setProduct_image(String product_image) {
        this.product_image = product_image;
    }


    public String getProduct_price() {
        return product_price;
    }
    public void setProduct_price(String product_price) {
        this.product_price = product_price;
    }
    public String getProduct_src() {
        return product_src;
    }
    public void setProduct_src(String product_src) {
        this.product_src = product_src;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getCategory() {
        return Category;
    }
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        Category = category;
    }

}
```

.Can anybody help?
Any help will be highly appreciated.I am new to this enviornment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the code to insert into mongodb using setters and getters.

*Note that*

*1) I have used the same `Encapsulation` class with getters and setters.*

*2) I have used `mongo-java-driver-2.12.2.jar` as mongo java driver.*

*3) mongodb is running at port 27017.*

**Code:**

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class MongoInsert {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    Encapsulation bean=new Encapsulation();
    // Setting values
    bean.setId("value1");
    bean.setProduct_name("value2");
    bean.setProduct_image("value3");
    bean.setProduct_price("value4");
    bean.setProduct_src("value5");
    bean.setProduct_url("value6");
    bean.setDate("value7");
    bean.setCountry("value8");
    bean.setCategory("value9");

    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("Test");    
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycol");

    //getting values and assigning to mongo field
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("id", bean.getId()).
                             append("Product_name", bean.getProduct_name()).
                             append("Product_image", bean.getProduct_image()).
                             append("Product_price", bean.getProduct_price()).
                              append("Product_src", bean.getProduct_src()).
                              append("Product_url", bean.getProduct_url()).
                              append("Date", bean.getDate()).
                              append("Country", bean.getCountry()).
                              append("Category", bean.getCategory());                                                                                       

                              coll.insert(doc); 
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Kundera is no longer maintained.

---

You want to map your POJO with MongoDB database. you can use ORM for that purpose. You can achieve CRUD and query operations easily in SQL manner using Kundera. Kundera is a JPA 2.1 compliant object-datastore mapping library for NoSQL datastores. You can find more about Kundera on below mentioned link.

https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki

Hope that Helps...:)